# Libs and linker with CMake and MySQL C++ Connector?

Tags: c++, mysql, c++11, cmake, mysql-connector

I download the MySQL C++ Connector, I need it for a project in CLion, now, I was trying to make it run, but it was all in vain, I get the error -1073741515 (0xC0000135), i've read that is about a linking or lib problem.

My current CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(Entrenamiento CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
set(Entrenamiento_VERSION_MAJOR 1)
set(Entrenamiento_VERSION_MINOR 0)
add_library(mysqlcppconn SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
    mysqlcppconn
    PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/opt/mysqlcppconn.dll"
    IMPORTED_IMPLIB "C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/opt/mysqlcppconn.lib")
link_directories("C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/opt")
add_executable(Entrenamiento ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(Entrenamiento mysqlcppconn)
```

My code is this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

int main() {
   try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;
        driver = get_driver_instance();  //HERE IS THE ERROR

    } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        std::cout<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

and this is the error:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `C:/MinGW/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/opt/mysqlcppconn.lib` should not that be with .a extension instead of .lib?

Comment: Compiling from the command line is ok. Seems it's a matter of cmake