# How can i configure mysql connector and boost library with cmake on windows?

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, boost, cmake

I have a CMake project which use `libmysqlcppconn-dev` and `boost` library. The project build and works fine on linux but i had some issues to build it on windows.

I generated the visual studio solution and i doesn't find a solution to correctly install these 2 libraries.
This is my current CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

include_directories(features)
include_directories(lib/)

file(GLOB RPCORE_SRC
    Core/Util/*.h
    Core/Util/*.cpp
    Core/Inventory/*.h
    Core/Inventory/*.cpp    
    Core/*.h
    Core/*.cpp
)

add_library(RPCore SHARED ${RPCORE_SRC} )
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(RPCore PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_include_directories(RPCore PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_compile_definitions(RPCore PUBLIC RPCore=V1.0.0)
target_link_libraries(RPCore -lmysqlcppconn)
```

when i want to build the project it cannot locate these libraries and the include files.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'mysql_connection.h': No such file or directory   RPCore  d:\testrp\rp\features\core\util\database.h  5   
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'boost/shared_ptr.hpp': No such file or directory RPCore  d:\testrp\rp\features\core\data.h   37
```

How can i correctly configure them?

Comment: "it cannot locate these libraries and the include files." - This description is quite *vague*. Please, add to the question post your code and **exact** error message. See also [ask].

Comment: It's a project with more than 50 files so i can't put all the source code.

Comment: You have provided very little information about this issue, a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is typically recommended. Please provide the CMake **code** you use for this project, and tell us how you installed each of these libraries on your Windows machine.

Comment: In your `CMakeLists.txt` I don't see adding include directories related to mysqlcppconn and Boost. There are plenty questions on Stack Overflow about using Boost in CMake, just follow one of them. There are questions about using mysqlcppconn too. That question post contains an example of such usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265014/libs-and-linker-with-cmake-and-mysql-c-connector.